# Personalizar register en Auth laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

El modulo auth trae por defecto la opcion register afuera, osea antes de la sesion, pero yo quiero dejar el register dentro, osea despues de la sesion, y que lo pueda llamar desde otro boton.

Lo he intentando, pero en vez de cargarme el formulario register, se va a la direccion home, no se por que.

view panel https://paste.laravel.io/a0766f68-5b07-4fb6-8dad-a6c2b963d5…

routes https://paste.laravel.io/35df7d13-84ab-4c18-a7f8-3156657f87…

Comment: Puede que no estés configurando el Middleware

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/4d2a8c70-a3a6-4a0c-b544-916eb17c0bef

Comment: Este es mi register controller, aparentemente se ve bien

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a lo que comentas pero revisa el middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated, que será que te está enviando a home si ya te has validado como usuario, cosa que implicaría que ya te hubieras registrado...

Comment: En middleware RedirectIFAuthenticated si estaba en /home, lo reemplace por la ruta que necesito... pero ahora sale este error.

Comment: Esta página no funciona
La página crudgobernaciontres.test te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.
Borrar las cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

Oye amigo no se si ya hayas encontrado la respuesta, pero yo inetente lo mismo.
tienes que hacer un nuevo controlador con el nombre que quieras, RegistroController etc.
que sea de tipo recurso (resouce), en automatico te crea las funciones para el crud create, update, delete, etc.
importas el modelo de la tabla Users, y en el metodo store creas tu variable para validar, etc. antes de insertar los datos a la base de datos usas Hash de la misma forma en que se usa en el RegisterController por defecto, y con eso ya esta lo inserta y queda dentro de tu Autenticacion.